# How can I compile JS without merging on Laravel mix?

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

How can I compile JS without merging on Laravel mix?

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/*', 'public/js');
```

The code above results in all the js files in the js directory being merged into one file.

But, I want to get a result like below code.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/js/a.js', 'public/js/a.js');
mix.js('resources/js/b.js', 'public/js/b.js');
...
mix.js('resources/js/z.js', 'public/js/z.js');
```

Comment: And your desired code doesn't work? Any errors?

Comment: try this ```mix.js('resources/js/a.js', 'public/js').js('resources/js/b.js', 'public/js');```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `copy`.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.copy('resources/js', 'public/js');
```

Above will copy entire files inside `resources/js` into `public/js` directory.